# Sort a list of database fetched from MongoDB

Tags: .net, mongodb, linq, c#-2.0

Tried coding

```
Client = new MongoClient($"mongodb://{connectionParameters}");

List<dynamic> names = Client.ListDatabases().ToList()
      .Select(x => new { name = x["name"].ToString() })
      .OrderBy(x => x.name)
      ;
```

but the compiler shows error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>      'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<>'
>      to
>      'System.Collections.Generic.List'.
>
> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Not sure what the remedy is.

Also tried

```
List<string> names = Client.ListDatabases().ToList()
    .Select(x => x["name"].ToString())
    ;
```

but also errored

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) you'll see that it returns:

> `IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>`

but you expect it to be a `List`, so you simply need a last call of `ToList()` at the end

```
List<dynamic> names = Client.ListDatabases().ToList()
      .Select(x => new { name = x["name"].ToString() })
      .OrderBy(x => x.name)
      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use the `ListDatabaseNames` method of the client?

```cs
var dbNames = client.ListDatabaseNames()
                    .ToList()
                    .OrderBy(n => n)
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm guessing because I saw an example with, or found documentation for,  `ListDatabases` first :)